# compare 2 arrays and check the positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have 2 arrays, one has 10 elements and the other one 3, I need to create a new array with the same size of the biggest vector, with a boolean checking true in the position where exist some element from the array of 3 elements

I have the following arrays

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array2 = [4,6,10]
```

I tried making 2 for loops

```
for(var i=0; i<array1.lenght; i++){
    for(var j=0; i<array2.lenght; i++){
      if(array1[i]==array2[j]){
          array3.push(true)
      }else{
          array3.push(false)
      }
    }
}
```

the vector that I need would be

```
array3 = [false, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true]
```

Comment: If that's your actual code, please note that you've misspelled `length` as `lenght` in your loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also instead of another array use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and then [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the first away checking if the value is in the Set:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    set = new Set([4,6,10])

let result = array1.map(x => set.has(x))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` like so with `shift` like so:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const array2 = [4, 6, 10];
const array3 = array1.map(e => {
  if (array2[0] == e) {
    array2.shift();
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
});
console.log(array3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

If you just want a basic check as for whether the element is in the array, not the order, then use `includes`.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const array2 = [4, 6, 10];
const array3 = array1.map(e => array2.includes(e));
console.log(array3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: It feels wrong to mutate the `array2` in your first example, I'd rather drag an index along: `let j=0; const array3 = array1.map(e => array2[j] === e && (++j, true));`

Answer (score 2):

You can `forEach` first array and use `include` method to check if item existed in array as

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let array2 = [4, 6, 10];
let array3 = [];
array1.forEach(function (c) {
 if (array2.includes(c)) {
  array3.push(true)
 } else {
  array3.push(false);
 }
})

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would be more appropriate than forEach for this case: `let array3 = array1.map(c => array2.includes(c));`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep things simple and to use [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method to determine if array contains another element.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const array2 = [4, 6, 10];

const b = array1.map(el => {
  return array2.indexOf(el) !== -1;
});

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const array2 = [4, 6, 10];
const finalArray = [];

for (let data of array1) {
    finalArray.push(array2.includes(data));
}
```